# Normalizr schema for array of objects for Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalization, normalizr

I have a current response from my api as the following:

```
[
   {  
      "device_id": "1234",
      "network_status": "Offline",
      "status": "Yes",
      "frequency": 50,

   },
   {  
      "device_id": "12345",
      "network_status": "online",
      "status": "no",
      "frequency": 123,

   },
   {  
      "device_id": "12346",
      "network_status": "online",
      "status": "no",
      "frequency": 423,

   },
]
```

Using the latest docs: 
https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#arraydefinition-schemaattribute

I understand that these docs have been updated so looking at other questions on stack I haven't been able to find similar examples.
The 'responseData' contains the response from the api which is an array of objects. [{},{},...]

My code is

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr';

const deviceid = new schema.Entity('device_id');
const arrayOfDevices = new schema.Array({
  device_id : deviceid,
})

normalize(responseData, arrayOfDevices)
```

I want to get the following output. An entity objects that has the device_id as the key for each object.

```
  {
  entities: {
    device_id: { 
      '1234' : {
        .....
      },
      '12345' : {
        .....
      } ,
      '123456' : {
        .....
      }
    }
  },
  result: [
    ['1234','12345','123456'],
  ]
}
```

However, I seemed to just be getting the following response with an empty entity and everything else being pushed into the result

```
 {
  entities: {},
  result: [
   {  
      "device_id": "1234",
      "network_status": "Offline",
      "status": "Yes",
      "frequency": 50,

   },
   {  
      "device_id": "12345",
      "network_status": "online",
      "status": "no",
      "frequency": 123,

   },
   {  
      "device_id": "12346",
      "network_status": "online",
      "status": "no",
      "frequency": 423,

   },
  ]
}
```

What do I seem to be missing for my normalizr code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normalizr expects your entities to have an `id` prop. If the field that contains the id has another name you have to explicitly define it:

```js
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

const data = [
  {
    "device_id": "1234",
    "network_status": "Offline",
    "status": "Yes",
    "frequency": 50,

  },
  {
    "device_id": "12345",
    "network_status": "online",
    "status": "no",
    "frequency": 123,

  },
  {
    "device_id": "12346",
    "network_status": "online",
    "status": "no",
    "frequency": 423,

  },
];

const device = new schema.Entity('devices', {}, { idAttribute: 'device_id' });

const normalizedData = normalize(data, [device]);

console.log(normalized);
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "entities": {
        "devices": {
            "1234": {
                "device_id": "1234",
                "network_status": "Offline",
                "status": "Yes",
                "frequency": 50
            },
            "12345": {
                "device_id": "12345",
                "network_status": "online",
                "status": "no",
                "frequency": 123
            },
            "12346": {
                "device_id": "12346",
                "network_status": "online",
                "status": "no",
                "frequency": 423
            }
        }
    },
    "result": [
        "1234",
        "12345",
        "12346"
    ]
}
```

[image: Edit w0z95yy8zl]

Also compare with [this example](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#usage-3) from the normalizr docs.

I suggest to not name the id field `device_id` as that is usually superfluous if you name the variables that hold your entities correctly. If you e.g. have an array of devices you should name it `devices`. Then it is obvious that the `id` field of the objects inside is the device id. No need to repeat that in the property name.

Comment: This is perfect thanks @trixn. Thanks for the suggestion as well. I've also noticed it doesn't work so well for an object with a single array. Applying " [ ] " around "data" in normalize([data],[device]) device seems to work fine. Unless you know of any alternative methods. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you mean with "object with a single array"? Can you give an example of the structure of the unnormalized data?

Comment: Sure thing @trixn. It would simply just be const data =[{device_id : 1233, status: online, ... }] so in this situation only one device is returned from the api call.

Comment: @dankthreads Well if the api response always returns a list (which it should do) my example should work no matter if there are zero, one or multiple objects inside that array. Wrapping the api response with `[]` only makes sense if the api returns only the single object. You have to make sure your api consistently returns a list. If you want to fetch a single object (e.g. by its id) it should be another endpoint whose answer doesn't have to be normalized. at all